# What can cause a usb port speed change?

Tags: usb, udev

I have an [instrument](https://www.picoquant.com/products/category/tcspc-and-time-tagging-modules/picoharp-300-stand-alone-tcspc-module-with-usb-interface) connected via usb to a OpenSuse (11.1 32) computer. Following the vendor instructions, I've added one rule to udev:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="0e0d", ATTR{idProduct}=="0003", MODE="0666"
```

From time to time, and I don't know how to diagnose the issue, the usb changes from usb 2.0 to 1.1.

Having the instrument plugged in the port with the label "usb1" I can read that:

```
$ lsusb -t
1-1:1.0: No such file or directory
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 109, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M
```

In this case the control of the instrument starts normally and we can use it to acquire and process data.

But suddenly the communication is cut with an exception about the high speed of the usb is not available. Repeating the last command, I've got:

```
2-1:1.0: No such file or directory
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 25, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/4p, 480M
```

I don't really understand it, but it's like somehow it has change the bus. But the instrument is still in the physical place with the label "usb1".

Connecting it to the port with the label "usb2" I have:

```
1-2:1.0: No such file or directory
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M
```

Where the control works back. And if I connect back to "usb1" it changes to:

```
1-1:1.0: No such file or directory
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 117, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M
```

The instrument needs to have a usb 2.0 port to work, and I don't know what can cause this changes. There is no other usb gadget connected and afaik no one is disturbing the computer for its normal operation.

How can I diagnose it? A how can this be fix will be a plus... Can it have relation with the "*No such file or directory*" message received when list?

---

Answering [SamB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1820/samb) comment, it is a industrial environment. The computer has a [cPCI](http://www.adlinktech.com/PD/web/PD_detail.php?pid=230) chassis that is a 8-port PCI backplane, with a [Blade](http://www.adlinktech.com/PD/web/PD_detail.php?pid=485) that contains the computer itself. It has one cPCI [even receiver card](http://www.mrf.fi/index.php/compactpci-products/80-compactpci-event-receiver-cpci-evr-220cpci-evr-230) plugged.

I understand this make the question about an unusual system. But it runs a OpenSuse 11.1 without anything more special than the driver for the event receiver.

---

I have a newer update. Instead of thinking how can I modify the speed of a particular port, I've tried to find how can I disconnect and connect the usb ports from the command line, similar to what you do unplugging and plugging it again. Between many sites I've found [one with a bash simple example](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2013/02/usb-reset-ehci-uhci-linux/) and it did its part.

```
# cd /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd
# ll ????:??:??.?
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  9 11:32 0000:00:1d.7 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7
# sudo echo -n "0000:00:1d.7" > unbind
# sudo echo -n "0000:00:1d.7" > bind
```

With a minor adaptation of the script I can recover the usb port speed and relaunch the [Tango](http://www.tango-controls.org/) [device server](https://github.com/srgblnch/PicoHarp300) that controls the instrument, and does the data acquisition. The issue by now is that I need root rights to do it, but it helps because these equipments hasn't a very practical physical access.

Comment: I suspect the answer is going to be related to the specifics of the USB controller and board; could you give more detail about that? For example, what is the model number of your computer/motherboard?

Comment: Thanks SamB, I've added this information at the end of the question because it was a bit long to be placed in a comment. I like to know if, like the port has change its speed, I can change it back somehow.